# Yii2 extensions for reading and updating data from google spreadsheet

Tags: yii2

What are the different yii2 extensions for reading and updating data from google spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

There's yii2-google-spreadsheet at
https://github.com/sergmoro1/yii2-google-spreadsheet/blob/master/example/frontend/controllers/GoogleController.php